# Вывод данных из двух массивов JSON в PHP

Tags: php, json

Есть массив JSON:

```
{"city":{"id":2013159,"name":"London", "list":
[
{"dt":1459360800,"main":{"temp":-6.55,"temp_min":-6.55,"temp_max":-2.34},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"ясно"}],
{"dt":1459425600,"main":{"temp":-8.55,"temp_min":-10.55,"temp_max":-4.34},"weather":[{"id":700,"main":"Cloud","description":"Облака"}],
{"dt":1459458000,"main":{"temp":-10.56,"temp_min":-15.55,"temp_max":-8.34},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Clear","description":"ясно"}]
]}
```

он в переменной **$weatherDatas_json** 
Преобразовал данные формата JSON в переменную массива

```
$weatherDatas = json_decode($weatherDatas_json, true);
```

Чтобы вывести данные все **dt** делаю так:

```
foreach ($weatherDatas["list"] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["dt"],"\n";
  }
```

Помогите разобраться с синтаксисом вывода данных: хочу вывести из первого массива **list** данные **dt**, а из второго массива **weather**, например **id**, не могу получить, делал так:

```
foreach ($weatherDatas["list"]["weather"] as $key => $value) {
echo $value["dt"],$value["id"],"\n";
}
```

но так не получается, ошибка: *PHP Notice:  Undefined index: weather*

Answer (score 2):

Строчкой

```
$weatherDatas["list"]["weather"]
```

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу с id =>weather массива list. Элемента с таким id там нет.

Посмотрите еще раз на структуру того, что у вас есть:

- list - массив объектов.
- Каждый такой объект имеет свойства dt, main, weather.
- weather, в свою очередь, массив объектов.
- Каждый объект в массиве weather имеет св-ва id, main, description.

Итого у нас получается:

```
foreach ($weatherDatas["list"] as $value) {
  foreach($value["weather"] as $weather) {
    echo $weather["id"],"\n";
  }
}
```

Т.е. для каждого элемента в list-е мы выводим id каждого элемента weather

Comment: Спасибо! всё очень доходчиво